# Groovy concurrency: A better way to aggregate results semantically?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, groovy

I need to call a number of methods in parallel and wait for results. Each relies on different resources, so they may return at different times. I need to wait until I receive all results or time out after a certain amount of time.

I could just spawn threads with a reference to a shared object via a method call, but is there a better, more groovy way to do this?

**Current Implementation:**

```
        Executors exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

        for (obj in objects) {
            def method = {
                def result = new ResultObject(a: obj, b: obj.callSomeMethod())
                result
            } as Callable<ResultObject>

            callables << method
        }

        List<Future<ResultObject>> results = exec.invokeAll(callables)

        for (result in results) {
            try{
                 def searchResult = result.get()
                 println 'result retrieved'
            }  catch (Exception e)
            {
                println 'exception'
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you initialized the `ExecutorService` referred to by the `exec` variable?

Comment: I used Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

Comment: Thanks, I updated the code sample with this info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`AbstractExecutorService.invokeAll(Collection<? extends Callable<T>> tasks, long timeout, TimeUnit unit)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/AbstractExecutorService.html#invokeAll(java.util.Collection,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit))

The groovy part would be using closures `as Callable`

Comment: Any idea why I see only "exception" and no stack trace, or why methods that succeed normally throw exceptions?

Comment: @Stefan: No, but things to try would be debugging into the catch block, or printing the exception object itself to see its type and message.

Answer (score 6):

A Groovier solution is to use [GPars](http://gpars.codehaus.org/Parallelizer) - a concurrency library written in Groovy.

```
import static groovyx.gpars.GParsExecutorsPool.withPool

withPool {
    def callable = {obj -> new ResultObject(a: obj, b: obj.callSomeMethod())}.async()
    List<ResultObject> results = objects.collect(callable)*.get()
}
```